# Error in using command of follow demo

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

someone can you give me the solutions in this problem , this occur when i run `roslaunch turtlebot3_follow_filter turtlebot3_follow_filter.launch` ?

```
ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
ResourceNotFound: turtlebot3_bringup
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/icad/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share
```

then it continue to give an error in the next command ( `roslaunch turtlebot3_follower turtlebot3_follower.launch` )

```
ImportError: No module named sklearn.ensemble.forest
[follower-1] process has died [pid 11560, exit code 1, cmd /home/icad/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3_applications/turtlebot3_follower/nodes/follower __name:=follower __log:=/home/icad/.ros/log/21be3128-aada-11ea-9188-283a4d2fefa7/follower-1.log].
log file: /home/icad/.ros/log/21be3128-aada-11ea-9188-283a4d2fefa7/follower-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
```

please2 help me to finish my final year project

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354485/error-in-using-command-of-follow-demo/) by [irsyad](https://answers.ros.org/users/55370/irsyad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I see two different errors:

- ROS is not able to find the `turtlebot3_bringup` package.

  - Did you install `turtlebot3_bringup` in your system ? if not try to run `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-turtlebot3_bringup`
  - Did you compile from sources? If this is the case compile the `turtlebot3_bringup` package
- The error in the first line is related to Python: `ImportError: No module named sklearn.ensemble.forest`

  - You need to install sklearn in your system. Run the command `sudo apt-get install python-sklearn`

---

Originally posted by [ahcorde](https://answers.ros.org/users/50386/ahcorde/) with karma: 421 on 2020-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0